# Python variable values changes automatically

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am scrapping a website and everything looks fine except I can't save links in the website to variables and then to text file.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("https://website.com/list/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
file = open("newtext.txt", "w")
for link in soup.find_all("a"):
    g_data = link.get("href")
    print g_data
```

**output is perfect till this script**

but if I try to print g_data once more after the for loop is executed ,everything is gone..

```
print g_data
```

Only one link is output nothing else.Am I doing anything wrong ?

PS:I have tried this on different sites and it all outputs perfectly without any error.

Comment: have you tried printing out the entire r.content and see what the raw data looks like?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: @lionel319 yeah raw data looks normal.I can even print the links in for loop without any error.But when I try to print the variable  once more just after the for loop is executed its gone  only some garbage values.What are the chances a variable get automatically altered ?

Comment: it would be helpful if u could share the entire code you have, and the raw data(r.content) that you see.

Comment: @skyline75489 I just want the links(href) in the page.Nothing else.This is a very simple program.Is there anyway some scripts be included by the website that can alter the variables in python ? .I know its a dumb question but I am new to programming I dont know everything.

Comment: @lionel319 sorry its kind of personal information

Comment: @NeoStan You are printing `g_data` outside the `for` loop? As far as I can see, `g_data` is a local variable and will be invalidated after the loop is over. So if you trying to print it, it **will** not work.

Comment: @lionel319 No i have successfully done that in other websites.

Comment: You over-write g_data every time you save a link. Derek's answer below is correct to save all links

Comment: @Snoozer yeah...he is right.. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code that you've posted, `g_data` is only pointing to one `href` at a time. If you want it to collect *all* of the `href` attributes, you need to make it a `list`:

`g_data = []
for link in soup.find_all("a"):
    g_data.append(link.get("href"))`

Comment: Thanks Man... That solved the issue.I knew i was doing something wrong.

Comment: No problem. Some times it just takes another set of eyes.

Comment: I had this issue in my mind but I got other websites working perfectly.So I was shredding all my thoughts in the website design that they have done something to stop scrapping.